# How do i stop clipping of limit line text in ios-charts?

Tags: ios-charts

I have a requirement for drawing the limit line which is near to the top of the chart and I want to keep limit line label on top right. Is there any way, it can not be truncated. Please see my output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrUnG.png)

Answer (score 0):

try `limitline.labelPosition = ChartLimitLabelPositionRightBottom;`

if you want keep labelPosition on top right,
you may can try set  yourYAxis.spaceTop = x; 
if `x == 0`, the maxValue will match the top of the chart,
if `x == 1`, the maxValue will match the centerY of the chart,

sorry, I can't express myself well, but, just try it.
hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

The default renderer is little bit messed up. Subclass it (YAxisRenderer) and override method: `renderLimitLines`. Copy the content from original renderer and replace lines:

```
var clippingRect = viewPortHandler.contentRect
clippingRect.origin.y -= l.lineWidth / 2.0
clippingRect.size.height += l.lineWidth
```

with:

```
var clippingRect = viewPortHandler.contentRect
clippingRect.origin.y -= l.lineWidth / 2.0 + l.valueFont.lineHeight
clippingRect.size.height += l.lineWidth + l.valueFont.lineHeight
```

Now, as you have it prepared, you need to set your new axis renderer for

```
let yAxisRenderer = CenteredLimitLineYAxisRenderer(
   viewPortHandler: chart.viewPortHandler,
   yAxis: chart.leftAxis,
   transformer: chart.getTransformer(forAxis: .left)
)
chart.leftYAxisRenderer = yAxisRenderer
```